# Obter posição do mouse em porcentagem ao clicar na imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagem, posicionamento

Tenho uma imagem na tela e preciso clicar na imagem e saber o `position` da onde eu cliquei em relação ao X e Y da imagem. Por exemplo, cliquei no centro da imagem, então  o **X** seria 50% e o **Y** 50%.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
let imgWidth  = $("#fenimg").width();
let imgHeight = $("#fenimg").height();


$('#fenimg').click(function (e) {
    var posX = $(this).offset().left
      , posY = $(this).offset().top;
    console.log(
        ((e.pageX - posX) * 100/imgWidth) + '% - ' +
        ((e.pageY - posY) * 100/imgHeight)
    );
    console.log(
        ((e.pageX) * 100/imgWidth) + '% - ' +
        ((e.pageY) * 100/imgHeight)
    );
    console.log(
        ((posX) * 100/imgWidth) + '% - ' +
        ((posY) * 100/imgHeight));
    });
```

Tentei também ao invés de `offset()` usar o `position()` mas não deu o valor correto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz o teste pra div:

```
<div style="width:500px; height:400px; background-color:black" id="div"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#div").click(function (e) {
            var dataDiv = $("#div").offset();
            var clickX = e.pageX - dataDiv.left;
            var clickY = e.pageY - dataDiv.top;

            var percentXImg = clickX * 100 / $("#div").width();
            var percentYImg = clickY * 100 / $("#div").height();

});
```

Comment: Obrigado @Aline